# Does generic struct .ToString() method causes boxing?

Tags: .net, boxing

Does the following code

```
string GetString<T>( T? t ) where T : struct
{
  return t.HasValue ? t.Value.ToString() : null;
}
```

cause boxing, when all `T`s it is called with are enums?

This method has the following IL code (first part of method is skipped):

```
IL_0023:  constrained. !!T
IL_0029:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
```

I do not see `box` operation here.

Comment: What is generic `struct.ToString()`?

Comment: I mean generic method with `struct` constraint applied to its parameter.

Comment: `ToString` is not generic at all. You just use it in generic method.

Comment: Hmm, this really makes sense, shame on me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't cause boxing. When the code is compiled the exact type of `T` is known.

Calling `t.Value.ToString()` will not cause the value to be boxed, just as calling `42.ToString()` will not box the value.

If you call the method with a value that is not nullable, it will be wrapped in a nullable, but that is not a form of boxing because the `Nullable<T>` type is not an object.

Note that the IL code is not the final code. The code is compiled from IL code to native code by the JIT compiler, and the type of `T` may not be known until that step.